# Pivot error "cannot summarize the text" when column includes empty text strings

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am having a problem with the results of an array formula in Excel.

The formula returns the difference between the dates in two columns of the table `Details` where both columns contain non-zero numbers, otherwise, it returns a blank `""`.

###### Formula

```
=IFERROR(1/(1/Details[Date1])- 1/(1/Details[Date2]),"")
```

###### Sample Data

| Details[Date1] | Details[Date2] | Formula Results |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1/7/2023 | 1/5/2023 | `2` |
| 0 | 1/7/2023 | `""` |
| 1/7/2023 |  | `""` |

When I try to use the formula results in a pivot I receive an error "cannot summarize the text."

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Properly formatted dates in Excel are numbers, you should be able to manipulate them like numbers. Make sure you don't have text that looks like a date

Comment: What does `unicode text` in your title have to do with your question? In Excel, are these text strings that look like dates, or are they actual dates? You can tell the difference by using the formuls `ISTEXT(cell_reference)` where `cell_reference` is a cell containing the date.

Comment: Maddy if my suggested edits clarify or improve the question, please accept them.  This will make the question more useful to other users in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

###### Having your cake and eating it too

It looks like what you prefer for one application doesn't work for the other application:

1. Your first formula returns an empty text string if either `Date1` or `Date2` is anything but a non-zero number.

   ```
    =IFERROR(1/(1/Details[Date1])- 1/(1/Details[Date2]),"")
   ```
2. Your second formula is summarizing numbers and doesn't work if you include empty text strings.

## Solutions

#### Option 1:   Use `0` instead of `""`

Return zero instead of an empty string in your first formula.  You could then set your spreadsheet options to hide zero values if they are annoying to look at.

```
=IFERROR(1/(1/Details[Date1])- 1/(1/Details[Date2]),)
```

#### Option 2:   Handle the strings in the formula

If you are using a formula you can adapt it to manage text strings.

Without a formula, I can't really help but if `C1:C20` contains a mix of text and numbers and you want only numbers, replace:

```
=C1:C20
```

With one of the following array formulas depending on your Excel version:

```
=IFERROR(C1:C20/1,)
   or
{=IFERROR(C1:C20/1,)}
```

Comment: Can you please help me with the new question.Blind Spors

Comment: Thank you . Yes, solved. Can I get your help on other question that you edited yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

try this

This formula subtracts Date1 from Date2 and returns the difference. If there is an error, it will display an empty string (""). This should give you the correct result for the date difference in your Excel worksheet.

```
=IFERROR(Details[Date2] - Details[Date1], "")
```

Comment: The original formula returns the difference of two dates only if both values are non-zero numbers.  Your changes merely allow the calculation to now succeed if either column is `0` or blank (equivalent to `0`) and only returns `""` if there is a text string in one of the columns.  Also, your amended formula still introduces the core problem the OP is trying to solve (pivot error when values returned by the formula include text strings).